# How to add grass on a procedural mesh in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, procedural-generation, grass, urp

I was unable to find a good tutorial to help me in my situation :

I created a procedural mesh looking like an island in unity and I want to cover this mesh of grass but after a certain height (it's an island so I don't want grass on the beach...).

I think that I need to procedurally generate the grass when I generate the mesh but I didn't find anything that could help me.

I tried many ways like GPU instancing (i didn't understand well what it was doing), URP shader and more...

Please help me I have been stuck on it for 2 weeks !

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to use terrain grass, you need terrain. You can not put grass on a normal mesh. You have to convert your mesh to terrain and luckily there is a good solution. Follow this tutorial to convert [mesh to terrain](https://www.lmhpoly.com/tutorials/convert-mesh-to-unity-terrain).

And for adding grass based on height, you can follow this [unity answer.](https://answers.unity.com/questions/12835/how-to-automatically-apply-different-textures-on-t.html) Or, [this answer](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1141423/placing-grass-on-terrain-in-script-on-a-certain-he.html).

Comment: First: thank you so much for answering me! I wasn't expecting to use terrain grass, but it's a good point to start... I would like to have 3D grass with interaction etc... So I don't know if it's possible with the unity grass :)